# Unit Testing for a method that accepts MethodInfo objects

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I need to unit tess a method that receives a *MethodInfo* object of some arbitrary user-code method (loaded dynamically via reflection).

```
public string SomeMethod(MethodInfo methodInfo);
```

I would like to exercise this method using different *MethodInfo* objects.

The simplest way is to use `<type>.GetMethod("name")` to retrieve a *MethodInfo* object, then call the tested method using it and assert against the result.

I would like to cover as many "different" method info's (or more specifically, as many different methods as possible to be passed in).

I am considering 2 approaches, not sure if this is how it should be done:

1. Create a new test class with all methods i need on it. Use this type's GetMethods() and iterate those to feed them into my tested method.
2. Create a separate unit test per method.

The first option is easier to extend (add a new method to the test class), but contains multiple asserts (asserts against each MethodInfo instance it has).

How can we easily solve this issue and create a robust test for this particular scenario?

Comment: I think you want to over-test, you just need to test all the cases to cover you whole code (including exceptions generated by function called inside your method). Apart from that iterating over the methods of a Dummy Class with all the different methods kinds you want to test seems a good approach.

Comment: what are you testing exactly? MethodInfo is obtained from reflection. What are the expectations of the test? What does it Assert against?

Comment: Our app gets a user's method dynamically, serializes its parameters into xml and displays it. I want to make sure that no matter which method is thrown at our app, it will succeed in processing and displaying its args in xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create a new test class with all methods i need on it. Use this type's
>   GetMethods() and iterate those to feed them into my tested method.

If the logic in `SomeMethod` (which processes this MethodInfo) has generic logic which deals with all types of MethodInfo, then go by above route.

> Create a separate unit test per method.

If the logic in `SomeMethod` has specific case by case logic to various types of MethodInfo, then go by above route.

Comment: The only problem with first option is that it contains multiple asserts. This means the test will fail on the first assertion fail, and will not display ALL POSSIBLE failure cases. Moreover it will be harder to figure out whats wrong by the test name (in contrary to a test that contains the exact scenario in its name).

Comment: yes, that is true. But that's not my point. It's the internal implementation of `SomeMethod` that governs the choice.

Comment: SomeMethod does not care what kind of MethodInfo you feed into it. It's a general method that supports any kind of object.

Comment: there you go! go with option 1. Reason being it doesn't matter if 1 fails or 10 fails because to fix the failure in `SomeMethod` we don't have to do any specific case logic.